# A line up question where the position and the number itself should not equal in an arrangement

Tags: probability-theory

There are $n$ numbers, from $1$ to $n$. Suppose that the numbers are arranged randomly, and asks there is no arrangement where the position and the number itself are equal. How many arrangements totally?

For example, if $n = 3$, there are only $2$ arrangements,

> $2$ $3$ $1$
>
> $3$ $1$ $2$

I have thought this question a long time, but failed to find the answer.

Comment: These are called *derangements*, and if you look up that word you should be able to find everything you could want to know, and much more besides. I'm sure it has been discussed on this website before, probably many times.

Comment: I've given an answer, but also note that it's a classic problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an inclusion--exclusion approach. Let's see:

The total number of unrestricted arrangements is of course $n!$.

Let $A_j$ denote the set of arrangements in which the number $j$ is in the $j^{th}$ position. Then the set of arrangements in which there exists some number in its own position is
$$
\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j
$$
Notice for example that $|A_j| = (n-1)!$. In general if $I \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ and, then $\bigcap_{j \in I} A_j$ is the set of arrangements in which all of the numbers $i \in I$ are all in position. There must be $(n-|I|)!$ such arrangements.

Now, using inclusion--exclusion in this special case where the cardinality of $\bigcap_{j \in I} A_j$ depends only on the cardinality of $I$, we can compute
\begin{align}
\biggl| \bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j \biggr| &= \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}(n-k)! \\
&= n!\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{k!}
\end{align}
Subtracting this from $n!$ gives:
$$
n! \Bigl( 1 - \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{k!}\Bigr) = n! \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{1}{k!}
$$